# dealing with imbalanced data set in multiclass text classification

Tags: unbalanced-classes, multi-class

I need to build a text classification model.

I have a labeled training set and my goal is to classify the new unlabeled text
.

My training set is composed on 6 categories, that are imbalanced.

The categories are distributed as follows:
Category 1 -> 450 examples
Category 2 -> 400 examples
Category 3 -> 250 examples
Category 4 -> 150 examples
Category 5 -> 100  examples
Category 6 -> 50 examples

How to deal with such imbalanced multi class text classification?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should:

- Sampling
- Adjust your performance metrics (like F1 rather than just accuracy)
- Choose a cost-sensitive algorithm, for example, adding weights to the minority classes
- Algorithms such as decision tree, boosting etc. They are more adopted to imbalanced data set.

Comment: Could you provide insight into when which option should be chosen or why? With that addition this would be a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your data but there are at least four things you could try:

- Upsample the training set by copying the examples in each category
- Downsample the training set by deleting some examples from the dominating categories
- Use a boosting algorithm like [scikit-learn's Adaboost](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)
- Use cost-sensitive classification algorithm

Answer (score -1):

You can downsampling or upsampling but these are vary naive approaches. You could try to intelligently sample the data in order to "re-balance" the dataset. However, in any case: imbalanced data is very tricky and requires a lot of domain knowledge.

- Always measure accuracy with the AUC: This denotes the probability that you can correctly classify a random positive instance and a random negative instance. There is no issue of imbalance here.
- **Coevolution** with the genetic algorithm works well. You are evolving sub-models to collaborativley work together to solve the given task at hand.
- Bayesian methods also work well here. Provided that you have a good prior distribution

Honestly - that's the best I can think of. Imbalanced classes are lame.